# Cordova geolocation.getCurrentPosition throws timeout on iPad

Tags: ios, cordova, gps, geolocation, phonegap-plugins

I am using the phonegap plugin geolocation to get the current position.

I have tested the function on an Android Tablet and it works.

If i try the application on my iPad, I always get errorcode = 3 (Timeout).

Basically the gps works on the iPad. (I tested with a GPS-Test app.)

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(succGPS, errGPS, { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 30000, maximumAge: 600000 });
```

--> Result is the function errGPS with error.code = 3

Comment: What if you increase the timeout? May be 5 sec is not enough

Comment: I also tried it with 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the bug.

It was associated with ios8.

In ios 8, you have to update the plugin. I have used 0.3.10.

After the update to 0.3.13 it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

check whether your application have permission to access geo loc of device. It will ask only for the first time you open it in a ios device. You can change it in settings.